# How to log activity on Session Timeout or Window close

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my application, we want to log some activity and messages to the DB when the window is closed by the user or when the session timesout. Is there any tested code to do this? Is writing this code in Session_End method of Global.asax.cs the right way?

Comment: Note that there is no reliable method to run code when the user closes the browser - this is an oft discussed problem.  There is `onbeforeunload`, but this is problematic for a number of reasons (for example, it doesn't fire if the browser crashes or there is a JavaScript error/disabled on the page).

Comment: closing the window does not always end your session.

Comment: I agree with mellamokb, if javascript is disabled there is really no way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do something like this for the session (note that there is no guaranteed way to check for a browser closing). This approach will only work if you are using `inProc` for your session.

In your global.asax.cs

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //a value must be present to call Session_End so we pre-seed it
   Session["SeededValueToEnableSession_End"] = true;
}

protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //handle session ending
}
```

Comment: Thanks TravisJ..How exactly do I use Session["SeededValueToEnableSession_End"] ?